# What events are required for google search for retail recommendations model?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-search

I have a google search for retail project set up with ~25M purchase-complete events. For some reason I can't create any models for recommendations, because I do not meet the data requirements. I easily match against total purchase events and unique catalog purchases, but for some reason I always have 0 events listed under "10 occurrences per catalog item on average". I also can't wrap my head around why "OR at least 90 days of Purchase events in the last 1 year" is not easily reached.
[image: recommendation model requirements]

Here is some proof I have over a million purchase events in the last 90 days. I also have 188 total catalog items with categories and prices.
[image: total purchase events 90 days]

I must be misunderstanding what "events" are when google says I have "0 events" matching the required criteria. Does anyone have any insight into what events/data I need to import to create the "Frequently bought together" model?